# What's wrong with my car?

Tags: honda, clutch, prelude, fwd

I need Some opinions on 1992 prelude i have. Its the f22a1 5 speed . But I was coming home other day and going into 3rd and it made a odd banging noise then lost the gears. It wouldn't go into any gear. Had to push in the clutch and feather it to get car to move. I got it home and shut it off. Attempted to restart it and all I get is a humming noise. Won't even start now. Any idea's as to what it could be??

Comment: Welcome to the site. You're saying it won't start at all now? Can you put it in gear while the engine isn't running (since it's presumably dead anyway)? If you put it in gear, does the engine hold the car, or can you move it (with the engine off)?

Comment: Thanks lol. Yes it won't start at all now. When I turn the key  I get a grinding noise. Like the starter is turning over. But engine won't crank over. It will go Into gear while the car is off. And yes it can be moved while car is off.

Comment: I'm wondering if when you put it in gear if the vehicle will move?

Comment: No, it won't :/

Comment: Have you tried to push start the car?

Comment: No. I have not.

Comment: Can you put in neutral and move the car? I'd verify that the transmission is fully disengaged.

Comment: @radpin - It has already been established the OP can move the car when in neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your description I think that you have a serious issue with the flywheel / clutch assembly. "Banging noise and no gears" so no connection from the engine to drive wheels...

Then when you try to start it, all you hear is a humming noise : this could just be the sound of the starter motor spinning.

So, you need to get a good mechanic (friend / neighbour if you are lucky...) to have a look and investigate further.

Best of luck...